# Yii controller method SQL query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, yii

I am attempting to perform an AJAX call from a form, and writing a controller method in my model to pass a result back to the form. I am new to Yii SQL statements or retrieving/passing data in a Yii context. Could anyone guide/correct my logic in attempting to write this.

This is the original mysql query

```
"SELECT AVG(rate_syr_mh)FROM packaging_metrics WHERE country LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string($country)."'". "AND std_rate != 0
```

"
This is my controller action so far. I am not sure if I am on the right track here. The parameter $country should be the form input submitted from a form on a specific change.

```
    public function countryRate($country)
{

$country_std_rate = Yii::app()->db->createCommand() 
    ->select('AVG(std_rate)') 
    ->from('packaging_metrics') 
    ->where(array('like', 'country', '%$country%'))
    ->queryRow();

    return $country_std_rate;


}
```

How do I add the portion of my original query to avoid zero entries?

Also will returning the query in this fashion allow retrieval by AJAX to recieve the number result to be put into another form field?

Comment: What is SQL doing in your controller's code ?

Comment: is it not supposed to be there, please explain ?

Comment: Database interaction should be a part of model layer. Controllers should be only responsible for changing the state of model layer and current view.

Comment: +1, good question about cdbcommand. flow will be like this: view will call controller action with ajax, controller action will call model function through model instance, model function will query the sql return data to controller action, controller action will echo data back to view, view will receive the ajax response. teresko is right about query being in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I add the portion of my original query to avoid zero entries?

**Answer**

Look into how the query should be specified for [CDbCommand's `where()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#where%28%29-detail), the operator with the lowest [mysql precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) (but ofcourse according to your sql), should be specified first in the list:

> array(operator, operand1, operand2, ...),

In other words the evaluation of the where conditions occur in **preorder**, hence you specify the operators in a kind of **prefix notation**.

For example if you have:

```
Where (somecolumn like %somevalue%) AND (somecolumn!=somevalue)
```

you write it as:

```
AND (somecolumn!=somevalue) (like (somecolumn %somevalue%))
```

So this translates to:

```
->where(array('and','std_rate!=0', array('like', 'country', '%'.$country.'%')))
```

This can actually be better understood by checking the source code of CDBCommand, specifically the [`processConditions` function](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/db/CDbCommand.php#L1409).

---

> Also will returning the query in this fashion allow retrieval by AJAX to recieve the number result to be put into another form field?

**Answer:** Nope.

To return ajax data you should be echoing your output. Additionally you can use [`CJSON::encode()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJSON#encode-detail) to json encode your return values:

```
echo CJSON::encode($country_std_rate); // instead of return $country_std_rate
Yii::app->end(); // this is also useful in most situations, almost forgot to add!
```

---

**Note:**

1. `'%$country%'` will not work, but `'%'.$country.'%'` will.
2. preorder and prefix notation are my understanding of the evaluation, not sure if the yii team intended it to be that exactly!

Comment: One other question, is this the proper fasion of retrieving a mysql query by ajax in yii. As in, this logic belongs in the models controller as a function? Should the data passed to it be in the fashion I typed or be along of the lines of $country = _POST('country'); Also will this have to be added to the access controls to be usable as a model action? If so, how will I add a new function, do I have to partial render it with an action name to do so?

Comment: controller is fine. didn't get the second question, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: you are welcome btw, i'm glad i could help. consider reading the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and also [this meta post about accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). no hurry, i'm just informing you of how the community works.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. In other words, in my ajax statement when I call this function for example   url: 'PackagingMetric/countryRate data: ' my_input: $('#my_input').val() ' How is the data passed to my function? Do I need an actual parameter like I do in the code I originally typed?

Comment: i believe teresko is right however, don't have the sql directly there, have it in your model, then in the ajax call, obviously the action of the controller that you call should call the model ultimately

Comment: although that should be a different question, since you are a newbie here, i'll tell you :). if you have my_input:xyz then it is already sent as a variable named my_input. if you want to send it as country, then simply do `data:'country: $(#my_input').val() '` .  yes you'll have to add to accessRules, but what is model action?

Comment: you seem to have quite a few doubts, handle them one at a time, research a little more, do some trial and error, then ask a specific new question, trust me it's worth the effort. ok?

Comment: You really are a life saver!! You have clarified so many things I have searched days for with no answer. I won't have a chance to try all these things until tomorrow. Also, when you say the action of the model should call the model. To make sure I understand, you mean the action in my controller should retrieve the post data from ajax. Instantiate a new object of the model, and call the method I created with that retrieved data as a parameter?

Comment: Will do, I am slowly coming to understand how MVC frameworks work. I am quite used to writing raw PHP code, but this help should give me some decent progress before I get stuck again.

Comment: flow will be like this: view will call controller action with ajax, controller action will call model function through model instance, model function will query the sql return data to controller action, controller action will echo data back to view, view will receive the ajax response.